# refactor lambda expression as sonar showing as null on at least one execution path

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, sonarqube

I want to refactor this code as Sonarqube  showing as **'bidRelations.Where(x => x.Type == _appSettings.ResType).FirstOrDefault()' is null on at least one execution path.**

```
public new List<CustomerModel> BuildRelationLines(PH.ParserHubApiBidResponse vendorBid)
    {
        
        List<CustomerModel> bidRelations = base.BuildRelationLines(vendorBid);
       
        if (bidRelations != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendorBid.Custom2) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appSettings.ResType))
        {
            bidRelations.Where(x => x.Type == _appSettings.ResType).FirstOrDefault().CustInternalId = vendorBid.Custom2.Replace("-", ""); 
        }
        return bidRelations; 
    }
```

TIA

Comment: I'm more concerned that you're shadowing the method. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the response i want to fix this line of code :  bidRelations.Where(x => x.Type == _appSettings.ResType).FirstOrDefault().CustInternalId = vendorBid.Custom2.Replace("-", "");

Comment: Why are you shadowing the method? Do you know that's dangerous?

Comment: @Enigmativity could you please suggest solution

Comment: I have a solution prepared. I will post when you answer my question re shadowing.

Comment: @Enigmativity i am not sure on shadowing. i have to fix this piece of code. u can give your suggestion.

Comment: Can you show the full class and the parent class(es)?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `FirstOrDefault` may return `null`. You should check if it is `null` before accessing `CustInternalId` property.

```cs
public new List<CustomerModel> BuildRelationLines(PH.ParserHubApiBidResponse vendorBid)
{
    List<CustomerModel> bidRelations = base.BuildRelationLines(vendorBid);
    
    if (bidRelations != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendorBid.Custom2) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appSettings.ResType))
    {
        var relation = bidRelations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == _appSettings.ResType);
        if (relation != null)
            relation.CustInternalId = vendorBid.Custom2.Replace("-", ""); 
    }
    return bidRelations; 
}
```